# How to get textures of blender model (png or jpg format)

Tags: modeling

I've been a bit confused on how to get the texture from my .fbx file (get the texture seperately as a png or jpg) wavefronts only have .mtl which isn't an image and is very outdated
i would like to see someone help me on how to export ONLY the texture as an image file or how to seperate/copy the texture from my .fbx
(i used material colors to color my model)
Please help!

Comment: Hi and welcome here. I feel difficult to understand your question. Is it about fbx or obj (wavefront)? If one or the other, probably you've imported them. And about textures, they are just image files which can be loaded or saved separatly from the image editor. So?

Comment: Hello :). Also, are you exporting the textures, or importing them?